# Linq query for grouping

Tags: linq, group-by

I have to generate say Customers Report.

there is condition for grouping records like

```
grouped and/or filtered by CustomerFirstName\CustomerCity 
       or CustomerLastName\CustomerCity
```

What would this Linq query look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the grouping operator examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746 ?

Comment: You've asked eight questions. You've accepted answers on zero of them. You're asking us to write code for you for your job that you are receiving money for. I'm not playing along; I hope others don't. If you want help, ask a very specific question about an engineering problem that you are having.

Comment: Your description of how you want to group is confusing. Can you show us sample data and what your desired output is?

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple image representation of group by might help you

[image]

Full aricle : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)